# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace' For brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

i have a simple code for trying to rename a name files by replace some characters but I get this error:

```
name=name.replace=(")","")
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Code is here:

```
import os
os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/Desktop")
nfiles=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
new_files = [nfile for nfile in nfiles if nfile[-4:].lower()=='.txt']

for file in new_files:

    name = file
    name=name.replace=(")","")
    name=name.replace=(",","_")
    print(name)
```

Comment: No, new_files is contains name of files which extension is .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is a method that you can apply to strings, so you should call it this way `replace('old_str', 'new_str')`. You are not using replace properly, so use this instead:

```
name=name.replace(")","")
name=name.replace(",","_")
```

Comment: same things. What is different?

Comment: It is not the same, look, you have `name=name.replace=(")","")`, while you should use `name=name.replace(")","")`. You are adding an extra `=`.

Comment: @SAFAK, I have added a link to the official Python documentation so you can see the use of replace.